# server times out with str_replace and single quote

Tags: php, str-replace

I have a function to replace smart quotes with single ' and double " quotes. It works fine when I test it like this:

```
function convert_smart_quotes($string) {     
  $search = array(chr(0xe2) . chr(0x80) . chr(0x98),
    chr(0xe2) . chr(0x80) . chr(0x99),
    chr(0xe2) . chr(0x80) . chr(0x9c),
    chr(0xe2) . chr(0x80) . chr(0x9d),
    chr(0xe2) . chr(0x80) . chr(0x93),
    chr(0xe2) . chr(0x80) . chr(0x94)
  );

  $replace = array("FOUND SINGLE QUOTE", chr(39), '"', '"', '-', '-');

  return str_replace($search, $replace, $string); 
}
```

It correctly returns the string "FOUND SINGLE QUOTE" for left quotes and it replaces right quotes with chr(39).

However, when I try to get the left quote replaced as well by adding a second chr(39) in place of "FOUND SINGLE QUOTE", like this:

```
$replace = array(chr(39), chr(39), '"', '"', '-', '-');
```

the server times out. I have tried everything I could think of (including escaping each character individually with backslash and with addslashes(), and using the actual quote "'" sign instead of chr(39), but none of these worked. It correctly finds the smart quote and can replace it with anything except a regular single quote '. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a sample input string that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your request. A string like the following:

And so he said ‘I haven’t seen him’.

Comment: I can't replicate your problem in any version of PHP: https://3v4l.org/O0Tgs

Comment: Thank you for trying. I'm totally stuck. I've tried it in http://phptester.net and it works fine. Must be something to do with the server I'm working on. Very odd, it works with any other symbol I have tried, just not with chr(39).

Comment: It is very odd indeed. There must be something else going on. Have you looked at your PHP log files?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to it. It's a project for a "non-for profit" on a free server...

Comment: After a day of painstaking combing of the code I found the problem: it's in passing the string to the DB. Thank you for your help and apologies.